# Pause in a game, UICustomalertview / UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, customization, uialertview

I'm implementing a game, and now I'm implementing the pause function. But i've see some different ways to do it.
I've made a lot of research, with tutorials like this : [Tutorial](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2009/04/23/subclass-uialertview-to-create-a-custom-alert/)

But I've seen that your app' could really be reject with this kind of alert :

> The Apple documentation for UIAlertView says:
>
> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

The other ways to do it could be (as I've seen) to implement a UIView. But the advantage of UIalertviews is that the pause function is already implemented, and i don't know how could i do a same function that paused all the animations etc without using :

```
sleep(INFINITY);
```

What would be the best way for implement a pause menu and function to get a result like this (it's a picture from my drawer) :

[image: Pause function from my friend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need:

1. isPaused for pause mode indicator
2. Popover screen

First thing you should have in main game loop is BOOL isPaused indicator, so game knows when it is in paused mode. Treat paused mode as any other one with performing proper actions. It isn't very nice to stop the process as other actions may have to be completed.

Secondly, the popover screen may be a full screen graphics with desired transparency, or better: programmaticaly made black image with 50% transparency, so you can darken the background and display alert view on the top of view stack.

Little digression about design, you should divide two parts:

- UI which only controls game parameters
- Game loop which controls game actions

It is good to divide actual game loop from controls. Controls like this alert view should only manipulate displaying parameters and not invoke any other action (presumably CPU expensive). The game loop should run itself all the time when game runs displaying graphics according to state parameters.

Comment: Think that it's a good answer :) Just, if loop is paused, but one animation have already started, it will continue or all is getting paused if i put a loop while(isPaused == YES) { ... animations ... } ?

Comment: It depends how you implement it. If you use Core Animation, all started animation will perform until they are finished. I would not advise to stop the running loop just because the game is paused. I would rather handle pause as a separate game state though